# AspectJ And Spring eclipse configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, aspectj

When i create AspectJ project eveyrthing is ok. When i create new Project(Not with aspectJ) and i link a Spring libs it's ok also, but when i Create AspectJ project and then link Spring libs i am getting "User operation is Waiting, building workspace" - and it's never ending, or causes an error and i have to restart eclipse

I don't know what to do. 
I used aspect J from eclipse side http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/ for eclipse 4.3 kepler. - installed this with help -> install new software.
Spring libs = spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE-dist + apache logging 1.2. - I made a user lib and just adding to Project.

I use eclipse 4.3.

I have tried this in so many ways and don't know what to do

Before, I was using eclipse luna 4.4 and spring worked there awesome, but i had to change on kepler because i can't install aspectJ on luna 4.4

Comment: If you install spring STS Luna version from the eclipse marketplace it will include the correct aspectj and I recommend doing that way instead of installing aspectj on its own.

Answer (score 3):

I do not really understand your problem description, but if you want to use AJDT under Eclipse 4.4 Luna and are fine with a development build for now, try this update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update

It supports the new annotation processing feature which was just introduced in AspectJ 1.8.2, see this [announcement](http://andrewclement.blogspot.ca/2014/08/annotation-processing-in-ajdt.html) by AspectJ maintainer Andy Clement.

Good luck!

---

**Update 2016-11-20:** Somebody asked for AJDT in Eclipse Neon with Java 8. Indeed I have it running on my Windows 10 64-bit machine, always in combination with Java 8. The update site is:

<strike>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/neon/update/</strike> (no longer valid)
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/46/dev/update/

Comment: This page doesn't exist. Maybe you're talking about this page? http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/ It lists here the development builds for Eclipse 4.6 (have them installed already), but i haven't found anywhere the AJDT for Eclipse Neon (v4.6). Can you confirm the link please? For example, how can i create an Aspecj project using the AJDT on Neon. I have also tried this one: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/46/dev/update/ which also doesn't provide me with the necessary tools. Note that i also have Spring installed, but i don't think it's needed and i haven't even configured it.

Comment: Sorry, I first was too busy to answer and then too ill. Okay, the site _.../neon/update_ obviously does not exist anymore (I have no idea why), but http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/46/dev/update/ lists the necessary tool if I search from Eclipse. As I said, for me AJDT runs flawlessly in Neon. I vaguely remember that it was a bit tricky to install, but once it was running, everything is fine.

Comment: In 20 years I have never reinstalled an OS on any of my PCs. Upgraded, yes. Repaired too, but never reinstalled. You should not use a cannon to shoot a mosquito. Find the root cause and solve the problem. And if you are looking for help here, post a description of the installation steps, concrete error messages and maybe even screenshots if necessary.